# Why can I use `>>=` without an explicit or implicit definition?

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, type-systems

I have defined a type `X` as

```
newtype X i o = X { runX :: Int -> i -> IO o }
```

I have made an instance of `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` with

```
instance Functor (X i) where
  fmap f a = X $ \ i o -> liftA f $ runX a i o

instance Applicative (X i) where
  pure x  = X $ \ _ _ -> return x
  a <*> b = X $ \ i o -> liftA2 (<*>) (runX a i o) (runX b i o)

instance Monad (X i) where
  return = pure
  a >> b = X $ \ i o -> runX a i o >> runX b i o
```

As you could probably tell, I have been, thusfar, unable to come up with a definition for `>>=`, and so have excluded it. I expected this to error on compile, but in fact, all it did was raise a warning. Fine, so it doesn't check that all the methods of a class are defined, but then surely I can't actually *use* `>>=`. Nope, wrong once again. To my great astonishment, GHCi happily evaluates `let x = pure 5 >>= pure`. `Control.Monad` does not export a default definition of `>>=`, and I certainly haven't defined one, so how is this possible?

Comment: I can't get your `Functor` instance to typecheck. It complains that it can't match type `IO (f0 a)` with `i0 -> IO o0`.

Comment: The code as posted doesn't compile (e.g. it should be `runX a i o` in the `fmap` definition). Perhaps you pasted a wrong version here?

Comment: That still doesn't work for me, but taking out the `liftA` does.

Comment: Still doesn't typecheck. I think you don't need the `fmap` in the `fmap` definition, nor the `liftA2` in the `(<*>)` one. If I remove them, it typechecks and I get the warning you describe.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Again, my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: This is a slight variation of my actual code, and I did not compile it before posting here as I should have. I have now and it works correctly.

Comment: No, you still have a `liftA2` too much :P

Comment: It looks to me like you should be able to define `>>=` and quit worrying. Have you tried out typed holes yet? They're really helpful for figuring out how to put things together.

Comment: I believe GHC does raise a *warning*. But it may require compiling with `-Wall` option. Moreover, if you define a class you may use the [`MINIMAL`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html) to tell the compiler exactly which methods the instance should provide. In this way you can provide mutual recursive default implementations and still let the compiler know that at least one of the two methods must be implemented to make things work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given your corrected definition, if I try to define and then use `x`, I get the expected runtime exception:

```
λ> let x = pure 5 >>= pure :: X Int Int
λ> runX x 5 5
*** Exception: foo.hs:12:10-20: No instance nor default method for class operation GHC.Base.>>=
```

There are two possible reasons why you would not see that.

The first is that you just ran the `let` but never tried evaluating the result. Since Haskell is lazy, `let x = ...` doesn't actually do anything. `x` will only get evaluated when you actually try to use it (with, ie, `runX`), so that's when you would hit the error.

The other possibility is that you used a `let` without specifying the type:

```
λ> let x = pure 5 >>= pure
λ> x
5
```

Here, `x` is polymorphic in the monad `m` it uses. To print something useful for polymorphic terms like this one, ghci defaults `m` to `IO`, which works correctly and gives you `5`, but doesn't tell you anything useful about your custom monad.

Comment: This is what I would have expected as well, but neither are true. I used a highly type restricted function rather than the `pure`s here, and I tried simply plugging `x` into GHCi. It succeeded without error. However, the `IO` that I was using actually represented the creation of a WX widget, and when I attempted to evaluate that I got a SegFault. Any thoughts on what in wxHaskell might cause this?

Comment: @Kwarrtz: That turns it into a different question, and I'm not sure how much I can help. I think you'd be best off asking that separately with more details specific to your case.